# Modal won't close when clicking outside of area

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

So there are two modals, a login modal and a signup modal, for some reason the signup modal won't close when clicking outside of it's area, but the login modal will and quite frankly I'm at a loss, I'm probably missing something very simple though... I've included the relevant code.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="position:absolute; width:100px; margin-left:1440px; margin-top: 10px; font-size:15px; color:white; ">Sign Up</button>

<!-- The Modal (contains the Sign Up form) -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" style="background-color:darkslategray;">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input style="background-color:black" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input style="background-color:black" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input style="background-color:black" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
      </label>

      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:white">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="signup" style="width:210px; margin-left:550px;">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style=" position:absolute; width:100px; margin-left:1335px; margin-top:10px; font-size:15px; color:white; ">Login</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" style="background-color:darkslategray">

    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input style="background-color:black" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input style="background-color:black" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <button type="submit" style="width:210px; margin-left:550px;">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#" style="color:white">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Edit 1: Javascript update

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work. Can you please make a proper working [mre]? Thanks.

Comment: Hey I did try to, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to import my CSS into a snippet, it keeps giving me the error:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"... Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you just messed up in your demo code but you declared:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
```

and then you redeclare the same variable, overwriting the sign up modal:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');
```

Try to keep your variable names like so: `modalSignUp` and `modalLogIn` to avoid redeclaring variables with the same name

Comment: Hey yep that was certainly part of it, as you can probably tell I'm not very experienced lmao. I've updated my OP with the Javascript, can you see any reason why it wouldn't be working as-is?